# stuck on float manipulation task

Tags: python

this is the task im busy with:

Write a program that starts by asking the user to input 10 floats (these can
be a combination of whole numbers and decimals). Store these numbers
in a list.

- Find the total of all the numbers and print the result.
- Find the index of the maximum and print the result.
- Find the index of the minimum and print the result.
- Calculate the average of the numbers and round off to 2 decimal places.
  Print the result.
- Find the median number and print the result.

Compulsory Task 2

Follow these steps:

- Create

this is what i have but getting the following error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:
```

CODE:

```
user_numbers = []

#input request from user 
numbers = int(input("Please enter a list of 10 numbers (numbers can be whole or decimal):"))

for i in range(0,numbers):
    el = float(input())

user_numbers.append(el)
print("Your list of 10 numbers:" + str(user_numbers))
```

Comment: `int(input(...` will try to create a _single_ integer; it won't be making a list

Comment: I think instead of `numbers = int(input("Please enter..."))` you want just `print("Please enter...")`, since you don't actually expect any input there.  You also want the `user_numbers.append(el)` to be inside the `for` loop (indent it so it lines up with `el = float(input())` -- and you might have an easier time using the program if you add a prompt, like `el = float(input(f"Number {i}: "))`.

Comment: All you need to do is indent the `user_numbers.append(el)` line so it is inside the loop.  The rest is just fine.

Comment: @TimRoberts have indented and still gives same Value error message

Comment: Since you're supposed to do 10 numbers always, why not do `numbers = 10` instead of asking for input?

Answer (score -1):

you can refer to the solution :

```
user_numbers = []

#input request from user 
numbers = list(map(float, input().split()))

print("total of all the numbers : " + str(sum(numbers)))
print("index of the maximum : " + str(numbers.index(max(numbers)) + 1))
print("index of the minimum : " + str(numbers.index(min(numbers)) + 1))
print("average of the numbers and round off to 2 decimal places : " + str(round(sum(numbers)/len(numbers),2)))

numbers.sort()
mid = len(numbers)//2
result = (numbers[mid] + numbers[~mid]) / 2
print("median number :" + str(result))
```

let me know if you have any doubts.
Thanks

Comment: Please use correct upper case letters.

Comment: Please use correct upper case letters.